# Squared loss function proof

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, linear-regression, newton-raphson

\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{w} &= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} P(y_1,\mathbf{x}_1,...,y_n,\mathbf{x}_n|\mathbf{w})\\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i,\mathbf{x}_i|\mathbf{w}) & \textrm{(Because of independence.)}\\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{w})P(\mathbf{x}_i|\mathbf{w}) \\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{w})P(\mathbf{x}_i) & \textrm{($\mathbf{x}_i$ is independent of $\mathbf{w}$)}\\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \prod_{i=1}^n P(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{w}) & \textrm{($P(\mathbf{x}_i)$ is a constant - can be dropped.)}\\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \sum_{i=1}^n \log\left[P(y_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{w})\right] \\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ \log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right) + \log\left(e^{-\frac{(\mathbf{x}_i^\top\mathbf{w}-y_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\right] \\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i^\top\mathbf{w}-y_i)^2 \\
&= \operatorname*{argmin}_{\mathbf{\mathbf{w}}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_i^\top\mathbf{w}-y_i)^2 \\
\end{aligned}

In the last couple of steps, can anyone clarify why $\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$ is replaced with $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Add explanations of the expressions might help the reader

Comment: This is the loss function that needs to be minimized, via gradient descent or Newton's method, in order to get OLS coefficients.

Comment: Since the minimiser of the final expression is just the minimiser of $
\mathbf{w}^\top \mathbf{X} \mathbf{w}-2 \mathbf{y} ^\top \mathbf{w}$, where $
\displaystyle\mathbf{X}= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^\top\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\mathbf{y}= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \mathbf{x}_i\ $, regardless of what positive factor it is multiplied by, there seems to me to be no obvious reason (at least from what has been presented here) why the expression should have been multiplied by the particular quantity $\ \frac{1}{n}\ $.  I can only suggest that a reason might emerge from the subsequent context.